# Chaining Filter in Django in another statement

Tags: django

I have been searching about how to chain Django Filters and I understood the examples given by the docs. But it does not show the equivalent of this filtering.

```
queryset = Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')
queryset = queryset.filter(entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

Is this the same as this?

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon', entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

Since it filters first the blogs with headline `Lennon` and then from the filtered blogs, it will filter again with `pub date 2008`. So basically it only returns Blogs with `Lennon` as the headline and with a `pub date 2008`

Or this?

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon').filter(entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

Since it is just like making the second filter on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code fragment is equal to the third one:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon').filter(entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

But *not* to:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon', entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

Indeed if you use two `.filter(..)`s, and these filter on related models, that means it will make two independent JOINS that are filtered. This thus means that you look for blogs where there is an entry where the headline is `Lennon`, and an entry (that can be the same or a *different* entry that was published in 2008).

The statement with one `.filter(..)` works different. This will return the `Blog`s that have an `entry` where the headline contains `Lennon`, and *that* entry is published in 2008.

Comment: Does this depend on Django Versions? I am currently using an outdated one (2.1.7). It seems that the first code fragment has a result same as the second one.

Comment: @JohnCymmer: no, in Django-2.1, the behavior is the same. But while the queries are different, it does not per se means the *results* are different. If a `Blog` for example only has an entry in 2008 about Lennon, both will return the same data. Normally the result will be different if you have for example a `Blog` with two entries. One with a `headline` that contains `Lennon` *not* published in 2008, and another, published in 2008 with a headline *not* containing `Lennon`.

Comment: why does this not work? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371388/why-does-chain-filtering-return-only-the-first-filtered-queryset