# Why does Chain Filtering return only the first filtered queryset?

Tags: django

Assume that I have a queryset nums:

`nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

The creator of nums 1 and 2 is: `user1`

The creator of nums 4, 5, and 6 is: `user2`

Then I have this code:

```
queryset = nums.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.filter(creator=user1)
queryset = queryset.filter(creator=user2)
```

Why does it only return `1,2` ?
If I understood the docs correctly, it should return `1,2,4,5,6`

Comment: I assume `nums` has a `ForeignKey` to `crator`? If that is the case, it only follows the foreign key. It will not follow a one-to-many or many-to-many relation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I tagged you in my other post. So in this case, it is now equivalent to the second fragment of code in my other post?

Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371388/why-does-chain-filtering-return-only-the-first-filtered-queryset

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
queryset = nums.objects.all()
queryset1 = queryset.filter(creator=user1)
queryset2 = queryset.filter(creator=user2)
final_result = queryset1 | queryset2
```

or using `Q`

```
from django.db.models import Q

queryset = nums.objects.filter(Q(creator=user1) | Q(creator=user2))
```